# Convert all rows into different in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that is showing a list of doctors and their details based on the sub-department they belong to. Below is the stored proc:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE SP_BILL_FOOTER_DOCTOR      
@subDepartmentId int              
AS              
BEGIN              

SELECT  HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME,              
    HETC_PAR_EMPLOYEE_TYPE.EMPLOYEE_TYPE_NAME,              
    HETC_MST_DOCTOR_SPECIALITY.DOCTOR_SPECIALITY_DESCRIPTION,              
    HETC_MST_SUB_DEPARTMENT.SUB_DEPARTMENT_NAME,    
    HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.DOCTOR_SIGNATURE,    
    CASE WHEN HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.DOCTOR_SIGNATURE = ''       
         THEN ''  
         ELSE ISNULL(SIGNATURE_PATH.DOCUMENT_PATH,'')+ HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.DOCTOR_SIGNATURE      
     END AS DOCTOR_SIGNATURE_PIC      
FROM HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE              
INNER JOIN HETC_PAR_EMPLOYEE_TYPE              
  ON HETC_PAR_EMPLOYEE_TYPE.EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID = HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID              
INNER JOIN HETC_MST_DOCTOR_SPECIALITY              
  ON HETC_MST_DOCTOR_SPECIALITY.DOCTOR_SPECIALITY_ID = HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.DOCTOR_SPECIALITY_ID              
INNER JOIN HETC_MST_DOCTOR_DEPARTMENT              
  ON HETC_MST_DOCTOR_DEPARTMENT.EMPLOYEE_ID = HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID              
INNER JOIN HETC_MST_SUB_DEPARTMENT              
  ON HETC_MST_SUB_DEPARTMENT.SUB_DEPARTMENT_ID = HETC_MST_DOCTOR_DEPARTMENT.SUB_DEPARTMENT_ID                
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DOCUMENT_PATH      
       FROM HETC_MST_DOCUMENT_PATH      
           INNER JOIN HETC_MST_TYPE_OF_ATTACHMENT      
             ON  HETC_MST_DOCUMENT_PATH.TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT_ID = HETC_MST_TYPE_OF_ATTACHMENT.TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT_ID      
       WHERE HETC_MST_TYPE_OF_ATTACHMENT.TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT_CODE='DSI') AS DOC_SIGNATURE_PIC  
ON 1=1               
WHERE  HETC_MST_SUB_DEPARTMENT.SUB_DEPARTMENT_ID = @subDepartmentId 
END
```

Below is the link of the output that follows when procedure executes :

[image: Output of Procedure]

I want to know is it possible to convert the rows in different column. Like the output has 6 columns and 2 rows, I want all the data in 1 row with 12 columns. Below is the sample output:

[image: Sample Output I want]

It would be of great help if somebody could guide me on how to do it. I have understood that by using Pivot in Sql, I can achieve this, but none I have found to my specific case.

Comment: I doubt SQL Server is your friend here. Why do you want such demoralised data? I **assume** that if your query were to (at the moment) return 10 rows with 6 columns, you'd instead want 1 row and 60 columns. Only way you could do it is with dynamic SQL, but I still don't recommend it.

Comment: Do you have a presentation layer where you could do this?

Comment: Also, bin the `1=1` in the `ON` clause, it's a waste of the compiler's time, and it can cause poor choices in the execution plan. Use `CROSS APPLY` (there's no point it being a `LEFT JOIN` either, unless you can think of a time that 1 does not equal 1???)

Comment: Also the SP_ prefix is not going to help you a lot. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix  For that matter you seem to have the same prefix on nearly every table. Maybe a schema would be a better choice than rather strange prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at updated code below:

```
select *, row_number() over(order by employee_name) rownum into #a from (
SELECT  HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME,              
    HETC_PAR_EMPLOYEE_TYPE.EMPLOYEE_TYPE_NAME,              
    HETC_MST_DOCTOR_SPECIALITY.DOCTOR_SPECIALITY_DESCRIPTION,              
    HETC_MST_SUB_DEPARTMENT.SUB_DEPARTMENT_NAME,    
    HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.DOCTOR_SIGNATURE,    
    CASE WHEN HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.DOCTOR_SIGNATURE = ''       
         THEN ''  
         ELSE ISNULL(SIGNATURE_PATH.DOCUMENT_PATH,'')+ HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.DOCTOR_SIGNATURE      
     END AS DOCTOR_SIGNATURE_PIC      
FROM HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE              
INNER JOIN HETC_PAR_EMPLOYEE_TYPE              
  ON HETC_PAR_EMPLOYEE_TYPE.EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID = HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID              
INNER JOIN HETC_MST_DOCTOR_SPECIALITY              
  ON HETC_MST_DOCTOR_SPECIALITY.DOCTOR_SPECIALITY_ID = HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.DOCTOR_SPECIALITY_ID              
INNER JOIN HETC_MST_DOCTOR_DEPARTMENT              
  ON HETC_MST_DOCTOR_DEPARTMENT.EMPLOYEE_ID = HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID              
INNER JOIN HETC_MST_SUB_DEPARTMENT              
  ON HETC_MST_SUB_DEPARTMENT.SUB_DEPARTMENT_ID = HETC_MST_DOCTOR_DEPARTMENT.SUB_DEPARTMENT_ID                
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DOCUMENT_PATH      
       FROM HETC_MST_DOCUMENT_PATH      
           INNER JOIN HETC_MST_TYPE_OF_ATTACHMENT      
             ON  HETC_MST_DOCUMENT_PATH.TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT_ID = HETC_MST_TYPE_OF_ATTACHMENT.TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT_ID      
       WHERE HETC_MST_TYPE_OF_ATTACHMENT.TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT_CODE='DSI') AS DOC_SIGNATURE_PIC  
ON 1=1               
WHERE  HETC_MST_SUB_DEPARTMENT.SUB_DEPARTMENT_ID = @subDepartmentId  )a


declare @iterator int=1
declare @string varchar(max)= ''
declare @string2 varchar(max)= ''
declare @string3 varchar(max)= ''
declare @string4 varchar(max)= ''
declare @exec varchar(max)
while @iterator<=(select max(rownum) from #a)
begin
select @string2=
'['+cast(@iterator as varchar(max))+'].'+ 'EMPLOYEE_NAME'+
',['+cast(@iterator as varchar(max))+'].'+'EMPLOYEE_TYPE_NAME' +
',['+cast(@iterator as varchar(max))+'].'+'DOCTOR_SPECIALITY_DESCRIPTION' +  
',['+cast(@iterator as varchar(max))+'].'+'SUB_DEPARTMENT_NAME' +  
',['+cast(@iterator as varchar(max))+'].'+'DOCTOR_SIGNATURE'+
',['+cast(@iterator as varchar(max))+'].'+'DOCTOR_SIGNATURE_PIC' 
from #a where rownum=@iterator  
select @string= @string+@string2
select @string4=
case when  @string4='' then 
@string4+'['+cast(@iterator as varchar(max))+'].rownum='+cast(@iterator as varchar(max)) else
@string4+' and ['+cast(@iterator as varchar(max))+'].rownum='+cast(@iterator as varchar(max)) end 
select @string3= case when @iterator>1 then @string3+' cross join #a ['+ cast(@iterator as varchar(max))+']'  else '' end 
set @iterator=@iterator+1
end 


select @exec = 'select distinct'+ left(@string, len(@string)-1) +' from #a [1] '+@string3+ ' where '+ @string4

exec(''+@exec+'')
```

Comment: Sir, my procedure is returning 4 rows, so how to show that in 1 row?

Comment: Since it’s sql server I would just create a rownumber for each line in the result set and then loop through each row and build your final set through there . If you have trouble with that I’ll demonstrate for you let me know.

Comment: Sir it would be very helpful if you could demonstrate it.

Comment: Ok will try to get to it today

Comment: Very much appreciated Sir .

Comment: Still working on it - hoping for tomorrow sorry for delay

Comment: No problem sir, appreciate your help. I am also trying from my end.

Comment: OK please have a look at updated code.  This worked on my own sample data but hard to fully test unless you provide me with the data you are working with.  This code should replace the code inside the 'begin'/'end' block of your stored procedure.  Let me know how you make out.

Comment: Sir, The first line "select *, row_number() over(order by a) rownum into #a from (", is showing an error that "Invalid column name 'a' "

Comment: Sir, its showing error after execution. Below is the error:                       (3 rows affected)
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'

Comment: Moreover, it should have shown data in one row, but its not happening.

Comment: Sir, I had to do some little changes, but your code worked perfectly. Very much appreciate your help sir.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer but a demonstration of how much using aliases can improve the legibility of your queries. Believe it or not this EXACTLY the same thing you posted. I just used aliases so you can read this instead of looking at a wall of text. The only actual change was to use a cross join instead of a left join on 1 = 1.

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_NAME,              
    et.EMPLOYEE_TYPE_NAME,              
    s.DOCTOR_SPECIALITY_DESCRIPTION,              
    sd.SUB_DEPARTMENT_NAME,    
    e.DOCTOR_SIGNATURE,    
    CASE WHEN e.DOCTOR_SIGNATURE = ''       
        THEN ''  
        ELSE ISNULL(SIGNATURE_PATH.DOCUMENT_PATH, '') + e.DOCTOR_SIGNATURE      
    END AS DOCTOR_SIGNATURE_PIC      
FROM HETC_MST_EMPLOYEE e              
INNER JOIN HETC_PAR_EMPLOYEE_TYPE et ON et.EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID = e.EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID              
INNER JOIN HETC_MST_DOCTOR_SPECIALITY s ON s.DOCTOR_SPECIALITY_ID = e.DOCTOR_SPECIALITY_ID              
INNER JOIN HETC_MST_DOCTOR_DEPARTMENT dd ON dd.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.EMPLOYEE_ID              
INNER JOIN HETC_MST_SUB_DEPARTMENT sd ON sd.SUB_DEPARTMENT_ID = dd.SUB_DEPARTMENT_ID                
cross join
(
    SELECT DOCUMENT_PATH      
    FROM HETC_MST_DOCUMENT_PATH p     
    INNER JOIN HETC_MST_TYPE_OF_ATTACHMENT a ON  p.TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT_ID = a.TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT_ID      
       WHERE a.TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT_CODE='DSI'
) AS DOC_SIGNATURE_PIC  
WHERE sd.SUB_DEPARTMENT_ID = @subDepartmentId
```

For the question at hand it is hard to tell what you are really wanting here. Maybe some conditional aggregation in combination with ROW_NUMBER. Or a PIVOT. You would need to post more details for this. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It's beautiful Sean. :)

Comment: LOL. At least if I saw this I wouldn't mind working on it. The original just makes me wants to take out my eyeballs and peel them. >.<

Comment: Sir, I want the output that is coming in 2 rows and 6 columns in 1 row and 12 columns. I know it cant be done through PIVOT, but how to do it, that is what I cant find and Thank you for the edit. Great help.

Comment: What do you mean it can't be done with PIVOT??? And seriously, post some details. I can't write a query against your image. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @Rahul what about my guess that your dataset might returns more than 2 rows? Is it a safe assumption?

Comment: Actually, @Rahul Sean's nicely formatted query made me notice you have a column `SIGNATURE_PATH.DOCUMENT_PATH` referenced in your `CASE`; that table isn't referenced anywhere in your `FROM` clause. Where is that value coming from?

Comment: I noticed that you hadn't aliased it, and thought "that's odd". A quick `Ctrl+f`: `'SIGNATURE_PATH.DOCUMENT_PATH'` told me why. :)

Comment: Yes sir, it will return more than 2 rows, to be exact it will return a max of 4 rows.

Comment: And about 'SIGNATURE_PATH.DOCUMENT_PATH', it will be 'DOC_SIGNATURE_PIC.DOCUMENT_PATH', I made a mistake while editing.